# Determine whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges uniformly on $(1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

> Detemine whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges
>   uniformly on $(1,\infty)$.

My attempt: Upon attempting to use the Weierstrauss M-test I get $$0\leqslant\|f_n(x)\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in (1,\infty)}|\frac{1}{n^x}|\leqslant\frac{1}{n}=M_n$$ But by definition, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. So the Weierstrauss M-test is not useful here. Is there some way I could possibly use the uniform Cauchy principle? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need the proof? It is the zeta function for $\Re x > 1$.

Comment: Yes. But you'd show the series is not uniformly Cauchy on $(1,\infty)$ (take $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1^+}\sum_{n=N}^M 1/n^x$; this is big for $M>> N$).

Comment: If $x$ is only a tiny bit bigger than $1$, you have to go way out to make the tail small. So the convergence is not uniform. Make this formal, perhaps by approximating the tail by an integral.

Comment: I understand the logic behind the hints, but I am unsure how would I show this using the formal definition of a uniform Cauchy sequence?

Comment: i.e. finding an epsilon such that $\Bigg|\displaystyle\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^x}\Bigg| \geqslant \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea**. If it converges uniformly then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ have to converge.

**Hint**

> Suppose it converges uniformly. Let's take any $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there is some $N$ such that $\forall x \in (1, \infty):\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n^x}<\varepsilon$. Let's find $M > N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^M\frac{1}{n}>2\varepsilon.$

**Final shot**

> It is obvious that if $x \rightarrow 1$ then $\sum_{n=N}^M\frac{1}{n^x}\rightarrow \sum_{n=N}^M\frac{1}{n} > 2\varepsilon$ (since everything is finite). But how can it be?